# Ignore EmulateIE8 in inner iframe in IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, browser, ie8-compatibility-mode, x-ua-compatible

I'm attempting to embed a "new" style page inside of an older page via iframe, but in IE9, things like border-radius are still having no effect when the page is loaded inside the iframe. When the page is loaded on its own, the rounded corners and effects appear just fine, but when inside the iframe, the css properties seem to be ignored.

Initially I thought this was DOCTYPE inheritance issues, but they're both `<!DOCTYPE html>` (outer and inner page). Next, I belive it's the `content="IE=Emulate8"` that's being inherited by the inner iframe. This is, of course, a theory. If it's an incorrect theory, please let me know. :)

Anyway, here's an example of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta content="IE=EmulateIE8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
</head>
<body>
    ... stuff...
    <iframe>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        </head>
        </html>
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Some of this may not really be relevant. Anyway, my question is: if the EmulateIE8 is the culprit as to why css properties like border-radius aren't working in the iframe under IE9, is it possible to override it or disable it inside the inner iframe?

Just to note: changing what's outside the iframe is difficult without changing the entire framework of the application, unfortunately (legacy apps *sigh*). I'm attempting to put something a little more modern inside of the legacy application.

Answer (score 4):

As noted [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):
As of IE9 mode, webpages cannot display multiple document modes. For example, consider a standards-based webpage that contains a frame element that displays content in quirks mode. IE9 mode displays the child frame in standards mode (because the parent document is in standards mode). Starting with Internet Explorer 10, however, child frames can emulate quirks mode. For more info, see IEBlog: HTML5 Quirks mode in IE10. For best results, however, use document modes consistently.